# php login works on desktop not mobile

Tags: php, session, authentication

On desktop you can sign in and it will take you to your account details with everything listed correctly. 
On mobile it will say you logged in successfully but it'll take you to the account page as if it were a welcome guest page. 
it worked on mobile when I uploaded it then suddenly stopped working.

login.php

```
<?php
include("includes/db.php");

?>

    <div>

    <form class="form-signin" method="post" action="">

    <h4 class="form-signin-heading">Login</h4>

    <input type="text" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required>
    <div class="checkbox"> </div>

    <input type="password" name="pass" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required>
    <div class="checkbox"> </div>
    <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" name="login" value="Login">Sign in</button>
    <br><p class="text-center"><a href="checkout.php?forgot_pass" class="forgotlink">Forgot Password?</a></p>

    </form>
    <br><p class="text-right"><a href="customer_register.php" class="forgotlink">New? Register!</a></p>



    <?php 
    if(isset($_POST['login'])){

    $c_email = $_POST['email'];
    $c_pass = $_POST['pass'];

    $sel_c = "select * from customers where customer_pass='$c_pass' AND customer_email='$c_email'";

    $run_c = mysqli_query($con, $sel_c);

    $check_customer = mysqli_num_rows($run_c); 

    if($check_customer==0){

    echo "<script>alert('Password or email is incorrect')</script>";
    exit();
    }
    $ip = getIp(); 

    $sel_cart = "select * from cart where ip_add='$ip'";

    $run_cart = mysqli_query($con, $sel_cart); 

    $check_cart = mysqli_num_rows($run_cart); 

    if($check_customer>0 AND $check_cart==0){

    $_SESSION['customer_email']=$c_email; 

    echo "<script>alert('You logged in successfully')</script>";
    echo "<script>window.open('customer/my_account.php','_self')</script>";

    }
    else {
    $_SESSION['customer_email']=$c_email; 

    echo "<script>alert('You logged in successfully')</script>";
    echo "<script>window.open('checkout.php','_self')</script>";


            }
    }


    ?>


    </div>
```

Then it redirects to your account details

```
<?php 
session_start();
include("functions/functions.php");

?>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">

<title>Deals</title>

<link href="../styles/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="../styles/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

<div class="container">

<div class="row">

<div class="col-md-12">



<?php include("../includes/header.html"); ?>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar" role="navigation">
<div class="container-fluid">

<?php cart(); ?>

<div>
<ul class="navbar-nav navbar-right navbar-small list-inline">

</div>
</div>
</nav>
</div>

<div class="col-md-4">

<div class="well">
<h4>My Account</h4>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
<button class='btn btn-large btn-block btn-nav' type='button'><a href='my_account.php?my_orders'>My Orders</a></button>
<button class='btn btn-large btn-block btn-nav' type='button'><a href='my_account.php?edit_account'>Edit Account</a></button>
<button class='btn btn-large btn-block btn-nav' type='button'><a href='my_account.php?change_pass'>Change Password</a></button>
<button class='btn btn-large btn-block btn-nav' type='button'><a href='my_account.php?delete_account'>Delete Account</a></button>

</div>
    </div>
        </div>

<div class="well">
    <div class="text-center"><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></i>
    <?php 
        if(isset($_SESSION['customer_email'])){
        echo  $_SESSION['customer_email'];
        }
        else {
        echo "<p><b>Welcome Guest:</b></p>";
        }
        ?>

</div>
            <?php 
            $user = $_SESSION['customer_email'];

            $get_img = "select * from customers where customer_email='$user'";

            $run_img = mysqli_query($con, $get_img); 

            $row_img = mysqli_fetch_array($run_img); 

            $c_image = $row_img['customer_image'];

            $c_name = $row_img['customer_name'];


            echo "<div><br><img src='customer_images/$c_image' class='img-circle img-responsive center-block'></div>";

            ?>


            <?php 
            if(!isset($_SESSION['customer_email'])){

            echo "<a href='../checkout.php' class='forgotlink'>Login</a>";

            }
            else {
            echo "<p><br><a href='../logout.php' class='btn btn-lg btn-danger btn-block' role='button'>Logout</a></p>";
            }



            ?>


            </div>

            <div class="well">
                <h4>My Account</h4>
                <p>Here you're able to view your orders, Edit your account, Change your Password, and sadly Delete your Account.</p>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="well">

                <?php 
            if(!isset($_GET['my_orders'])){
                if(!isset($_GET['edit_account'])){
                    if(!isset($_GET['change_pass'])){
                        if(!isset($_GET['delete_account'])){

            echo "
            <h2 style='padding:20px;'><i class='glyphicon glyphicon-user'></i> Welcome  $c_name </h2>  
            <b>You can see your orders progress by clicking this <a href='my_account.php?my_orders' class='forgotlink'>link</a></b>";
            }
            }
            }
            }
            ?>

            <?php 
            if(isset($_GET['edit_account'])){
            include("edit_account.php");
            }
            if(isset($_GET['change_pass'])){
            include("change_pass.php");
            }
            if(isset($_GET['delete_account'])){
            include("delete_account.php");
            }


            ?>

</div>
</div>
</div>

<hr>

<footer>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
        <p>Copyright &copy; Deals</p>
    </div>
</div>
</footer>

</div>
<script src="../js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You're wide open for a SQL injection and you're storing plaintext passwords. If this is being used in production you need to address these issues asap. As it is it would be trivial to log in as any user (amongst other things). It may also be possible to cause the application to reveal user's plaintext passwords via SQL injection. http://php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php

Comment: Yeah I'll get the passwords thing fixed. I was just trying to get the basic workings down. My main problem is that this works on desktop mostly but for some reason it'll stop working on mobile (my upload products doesn't work on desktop) . Only my log in for customers and adding a product to the database aren't working fully.